# Is salt really necessary for cooking pasta?

Tags: pasta, salt, water

I never put salt into the water when I boil it to make pasta even though cooking directions always suggest I do that and the pasta comes out fine. How necessary it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? The answers seem to cover all the big points. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/why-add-salt-to-the-water-when-cooking-pasta

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as a dup. If there's something different you want to ask, feel free to edit and we can reopen. But it sounds like the main difference is that your question is a little subjective - most people think pasta cooked in salty water has noticeably better flavor, but whether it's necessary is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt is not necessary, it's just a flavour thing, a common personal preference

I suspect you'll get a saltier taste by putting it in the water, than putting it in the sauce for the same volume of salt

Hot water is not necessary too, you can prepare dried pasta with cold water. But it doesn't taste right to me, so does salt less pasta :-)