# Is it good to add salt or oil to pasta water

Tags: pasta

Is it necessary as should i add salt or oil to the pasta water when it comes to the boil as before  i add the pasta??Does it  really effect the outcome of the pasta at all?

Comment: See also: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-keep-pasta-from-sticking-to-itself

Comment: See also: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/why-add-salt-to-the-water-when-cooking-pasta?rq=1