# How do I keep fettucini from sticking together while boiling it

Tags: pasta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep pasta from sticking to itself?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-keep-pasta-from-sticking-to-itself)

I have tried to add vegetable oil to the water.  I have tried stirring while boiling.  Is there a better technique?