# spaghetti dinner

Tags: pasta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep pasta from sticking to itself?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-keep-pasta-from-sticking-to-itself)

We have a spaghetti dinner at our church and the problem is is that we don't mix it in with sauce because some don't want sauce others don't want a lot of sauce some do. So my question is after I cook the pasta I put it in a colander to drain and it sets till ready to put in hotel pan on the steam table, however by then it's stuck together, how can I keep this from happening or how do I keep it from happening?

Comment: More or less exactly the same as http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-keep-pasta-from-sticking-to-itself

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I'd say exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add olive oil after draining and toss to coat.