# How do I keep boiled pasta from getting sticky overnight?

Tags: pasta

When I boil pasta and store it overnight in the refrigerator, it sticks to itself. Is there a way I can avoid this stickiness?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep pasta from sticking to itself?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-keep-pasta-from-sticking-to-itself)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, though, since she's asking about keeping it overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as it's cooked, rinse it with plenty of cold water, tossing it around so it's not stuck together. Then shake off as much water as you can and put it in a closed container in the fridge.

Some people like to put a little oil in their pasta-cooking water, claiming it makes the pasta stick together less. That's worth a try as well.

Comment: Actually, rinsing pasta rinses off all the good starch that you want on pasta so it sticks to the sauce. Just drain normally and add a **little bit** of olive oil and stir it up so it is lightly coated. Voila non-stick pasta!

Comment: @SteveChambers that's assuming there is any sauce to be added when cold

Comment: I agree with @SteveChambers.  Adding olive oil in the water accomplishes nothing.  The olive oild should be added after draining...

Answer (score 3):

Add I light amount of oil to the pasta 15 minutes after cooking. Mix well. You can also add in a very small amount of sauce after 15 minutes....than when ready complete it by adding the rest.